# Averaging granular samples the simplest way on SQL

Tags: php, sql, mariadb, query-optimization

So I have a fairly big table with granular price ticks (using MariaDB).

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
 `num` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `datetime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `pairs` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
 `price` decimal(16,10) NOT NULL,
 `volume` decimal(22,10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`num`),
 KEY `datetime_pairs` (`pairs`,`datetime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I want to make an hourly average of those prices, by type of entry, when the data is older than x days. For this example I'll take 7 days. I came up with this query.

```
SELECT `num`, `datetime`, `pairs`, `price`, `volume`, 
    AVG(`price`) AS `priceAVG`, AVG(`volume`) AS `volumeAVG`
FROM table
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`datetime`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') 
    < DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`datetime`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00'), `pairs`
```

The query takes ~25 seconds to run. I don't think I can optimize it.
This MIGHT print the result I'm looking for...however I'm really not sure what's the best practice to answer my question, once I have the data to work with.

Inserting this result, and deleting the old data? It would mess up the primary key number `num`, making it inconsistent with how `datetime` is ordered.

Updating old data using the result of the SELECT query, and deleting the old data minus those updated lines? That's what I'm trying to achieve at the moment...

I think that having duplicates of the table might not be an option, since I have an hundred tables like this to handle, and cpu ressources is also something to consider. I'm using cron and php to cast those queries. I might cast this operation every 12 or 24 hours.

What is a method that be would appropriate in this case?

Is the update query a realistic way of handling this?

Comment: Good lord, remove every single call to `DATE_FORMAT()`. There is no earthly reason to be doing that, and that's going to be the reason that the query takes so long.

Comment: Using `DATE_FORMAT` will prevent MySQL from using any indexes. You will get much better performance if alongside the datetime you also store number of hours elapsed since the epoch and index that field. That way you will end up grouping on an integer which is much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Any reason to use an 11-byte `decimal(22,10)` instead of a simple 4-byte `FLOAT`?
- It does not make sense to select `num`, `datetime`, `pairs`, `price`, `volume` when doing a `GROUP BY`.
- Build and maintain a Summary table, broken down by hour.  Then build the report from that table.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables
- Is there any change of two entries with the same `(datetime, pairs)` combo?  If not get rid of `id` and make that the 2-column `PRIMARY KEY`.
- Meanwhile, you could partially optimize your query

for hourly averages over the past week up to, but not including, the current hour:

```
SELECT  LEFT(`datetime`, 13) AS the_hour,
        pairs,
        AVG(`price`)  AS `priceAVG`,
        AVG(`volume`) AS `volumeAVG`
    FROM `table`
    WHERE `datetime` >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
      AND `datetime`  < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
    GROUP BY LEFT(`datetime`, 13), pairs
```

And

```
INDEX(datetime)
```

The Summary table approach is the most complex, but gives you the most bang for your buck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using decimal(22,10) because I need at least 10 very precise digits right of the decimal point and at least 22 digits total. (datetime, pairs) could change and potentially be not duplicate if for some reasons I ignore there's an hour problem on the server I use (summer time change, or whatever). Since I asked the question I changed my query a bit, needing to also group up to the minutes (5 min).

Comment: It's now looking like this : SELECT `pairs`, AVG(`price`) as `priceAVG`, AVG(`volume`) as `volumeAVG` FROM `table`
WHERE `datetime` < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10080 MINUTE) GROUP BY `datetime` div 500. div 500 groups by 5 min and makes the avg. I have no idea why and how, but it seems to be working while doing a fast sql check. My current plan was a bit clunky but that's 1.doing this query and storing it in php 2.select min primary key in this range with another query 3.delete granular data samples (limited space) 4.insert each rows with approriate id using php 5.do this once per table and day

Comment: Huh?  A "volume" is a datetime+pairs??  DST can cause duplicate time.  Consider `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: A `DATETIME`, when used in arithmetic, is treated something like `20171231235959`; using `div 500` may not give you the expected value.  First convert to seconds.

Comment: @user46987151 - and it sounds like you have the general ideal of Summary tables; just some hiccups in the implementation.

Comment: About `volume`, for me it's just a decimal not related to any index and I make an avg of it. I think I got the idea of summary tables, I didn't knew about it. However since space is an important parameter this might be more fitting for a future project with more space available. As for GROUP BY `datetime` div 500, I replaced it by GROUP BY TO_SECONDS(`datetime`) div 300. Which should be more accurate. The whole query with `div` seems to work better than what I thought performance wise.

Comment: @user46987151 - If a Summary table summarizes 10 rows into 1, then it will be about 1/10 the size of the raw data.  This is a small increase in disk space usage; probably small enough not to worry about?

Comment: The problem would most likely not be the summary table size itself, but the base tables constantly increasing in size if I don't touch the base tables; and if I touch the base tables, then perhaps I would rather insert the aggregated data in the right place in the table. The plan is to have ~100 tables for different data sources and 1 cron per table to fetch the data each minutes, so I would either need to create 100 extra summary tables, or to create one with one big summary...this sounds more complicated than it should for a similar result. (as usual time is also an important factor...)

Comment: @user46987151 - If the 100 base tables have the same schema (except for id of data source), then there may not be any good reason to have 100 tables instead of 1 table.

Comment: If a similar query would return the same result in the same amount of time between case 1. `select from table_X` and case 2. `select from table where field=X`, then yes there might not be any good reason. I started developing around the idea of 100 tables though, but can be changed at this point probably. Also feared of some possible kinds of failure which would affect all the data hence killing all the tool, as opposed to having 99 tables left to work with. Maybe an hardware failure could happen during a bad moment resulting in a working db but unusable table data. might be paranoid

Comment: @user46987151 - If you want to have 99 tables survive, spread them across 100 machines.  A single table crashing is much less likely than a hardware failure, or all tables crashing.

Comment: Probably too complicated to have it on 100 machines. I'll try to follow your advice and start to build things on top on 1 big table. Max size if leaving the data incrementing a year would probably be 6 billions rows, but if doing the above steps it should divide the size by at least 100 so all good.

Comment: @user46987151 - 6 billion rows is possible.  But let's see the main queries to see if we can optimize the schema, indexes, and possibly partitioning.  Will you be purging 'old' data?

Comment: Yes-not keeping data older than a year, granular data to be aggregated daily (older than 1 day group by 5 min, 2 days 15 min, 3 days 60 min and so on with weight accounted for to keep accuracy). If you're interested in the structure, I use 1 db, plan is to have that big table to host the data (structure above). 100 crons planned to feed the table every 1 min, with simples bulk `INSERT`. Simples queries are run on it `SELECT price FROM table WHERE datetime <= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) AND pairs = \''.$phpvar['pairs'].'\' ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1`. Inside a loop filling the var

Comment: Those queries are run once per minute, that's another 100 cron per minute. (1 set of 100 to fetch the data, 1 set of 100 to interpret the data as fast as possible). The rest is not yet clear, it'll probably be 1 cron running every min with a lot of if{} intepreted sequencially by php, with a logic of "locked" script to prevent it to run again if it runs for more than 60 sec. I happened to have a problem with the previous query however, in fact I needed to add a field to the group clause, and it's so long to run that mysql drops connexion. Might have to run a loop or crons again...

Comment: Query which is `SELECT pairs, AVG(price) as priceAVG, AVG(volume) as volumeAVG, COUNT(price) as AVG_weight FROM table WHERE datetime < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10080 MINUTE) GROUP BY pairs, TO_SECONDS(datetime) div 300`. Index is still (pairs,datetime), but I know that php can run this as many times as needed with the right `WHERE` filter. Probably not optimal at all but can probably work as intented. If you were wondering why the count(), it's to store the weight of the avg, to avoid losing accuracy.

Comment: @user46987151 - is the 6 billion rows _before_ aggregating?  Or _after_?  Do you keep the raw data for the year?

Comment: @user46987151 - How long does each cron job take?  I would hope significantly less than a minute.  There is a problem if each cron job actually starts working simultaneously at the top of the minute -- they will stumble over each other, swamping the CPUs and MySQL.  It would be better if they staggered themselves or simply ran continually, but slept enough to lighten and spread out the load.

Comment: @user46987151 - Note that continually running eliminates the need to prevent "running again..".

Comment: @user46987151 - Don't re-summarize all the old data, only pick up where you left off.  If that is the actual query, there is a potential bug -- the oldest 5-minute interval may be less than 5 minutes.

Comment: That would be max 6 billions after a year if I'm not aggregating anything, just letting the table fill up. This would take too much space for now, especially if for some reasons the sources start to provide x10 more data. The set of crons which fetch the data, usually takes 1-2 seconds max (each) to execute all the instructions. The set of crons which is interpreting the table data which tells the tool what to do next, runs under 1 sec each. I'm monitoring if a cron executes above 50 sec (if run time > 50 sec, insert into monitoring table) which should be enough to track problems.

Comment: For cron execution, I've heard of methods to trigger scripts in real time as needed, I think it is called daemon, but I'm not sure that this would be more optimal than 1 minute cron jobs. I'm monitoring the server ressource, and will delay each crons during the minute, if that is necessary. I'm running all at the same time now though, at :00. I'm not done creating the 200 crons yet, but will eventually have to delay the crons depending on how the server does. Running time should be OK... As for the query, you're right, don't need to check all the old data.

Comment: and as for the potential bug, if you referred to the last query that drops connection with `GROUP BY pairs, TO_SECONDS(datetime) div 300`, which is the query I use to aggregate the data, if taking the oldest 5 minutes interval returned by the query, it's possible that this interval is smaller than 5 minutes. This would not be a problem I think, as the query will average whatever there is in that interval (for instance if there's only 3 results ie interval of 2 minutes). In that example the weight would be 3 instead of normally 5. If that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

1. Converting dates to strings with `DATE_FORMAT()` is inefficient. Compare the dates directly.
2. Comparing strings is inefficient. Compare the dates directly.
3. You have no index on the `datetime` field. No, `datetime_pairs` doesn't count because:

   - `pairs` isn't involved.
   - `datetime` isn't the first item in the composite key.

So:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
 `num` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `datetime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `pairs` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
 `price` decimal(16,10) NOT NULL,
 `volume` decimal(22,10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`num`),
 KEY `datetime` (`datetime`), -- change
 KEY `pairs` (`pairs`)        -- change
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And:

```
SELECT `num`, `datetime`, `pairs`, `price`, `volume`, 
    AVG(`price`) AS `priceAVG`, AVG(`volume`) AS `volumeAVG`
FROM table
-- DATE(datetime) is the same as 00:00:00 on that day, but is
-- a DATE type that can be efficiently compared
WHERE `datetime` < DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY)
GROUP BY DATE(`datetime`), `pairs`
```

And you're *still* going to be constrained by `GROUP BY DATE(datetime)` because there's no index to use. You might want to add anoter column that's simply `date DATE NOT NULL` so that you can leverage an index on it, though the above should already drastically bring down the time required.

Additionally, the columns `num, datetime, price, volume` in the query will be pretty much meaningless since they're not referenced in the `GROUP BY` statement.

Also, historical data doesn't change, so you should never have to aggregate daily data more than once. Storing the daily aggregates like average and count would be enough to construct larger aggregations on top. Eg:

```
SELECT AVG(daily_count * daily_average) AS 'weekly_average'
FROM daily_aggregates
WHERE datestamp > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Leverage caching. I've seen a *lot* of performance issues due to developers repeatedly running the exact same calculations over and over on giant, historical datasets that will *never* change. Just something as simple as cached daily aggregates can reduce the data set from thousands or millions of items per year, to just 365.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. Please let me process this. I needed the `datetime_pairs` for another select query using this index, I'll see what I can do to sort this first issue. As for saving the AVG results, you were suggesting to create one new daily_aggregate table (that would contain the avg aggregations tied to each of the 100 tables), and to avoid touching the "base" tables completely for data older than 7 days? (to follow the example)

Comment: `INDEX(datetime, pairs)` will suffice for both that other select, plus this one.  `INDEX(datetime)` would be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need the hour too, not just the date? So just comparing the date part won't help you, I guess.

1. Adding a [persistent generated column](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/generated-columns/), that gives you the date with the hour but without minutes or seconds (they are set to 0) from `datetime`.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `table`
               ADD (`date_to_the_hour` date AS (date(`datetime`) + INTERVAL hour(`datetime`) HOUR) PERSISTENT);
   ```
2. Put an index on that column and `pairs`.

   ```
   CREATE INDEX `date_to_the_hour_pairs`
                ON `table`
                   (`date_to_the_hour`,
                    `pairs`);
   ```
3. Alter your select to compare to the new column.

   ```
   SELECT `num`,
          `datetime`,
          `pairs`,
          `price`,
          `volume`, 
          AVG(`price`) `priceAVG`,
          AVG(`volume`) `volumeAVG`
          FROM `table`
          WHERE `date_to_the_hour` < date(now() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) + INTERVAL hour(now()) HOUR
          GROUP BY `date_to_the_hour`,
                   `pairs`;
   ```

That might speed things up a bit.